# Differential Equations Question 2.0

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

$$x'(t) = -\pi - y(t) + 5.696592654$$
$$y'(t) = -(x(t) - 6.173)^2 - y(t) + 2.805$$

So the easy thing to do is solve for $y'(t)$ in the top equation:

$x'(t) =- \pi - y(t) + 5.696592654$

$x'(t) + y(t) =- \pi + 5.696592654$

$y(t) =- \pi + 5.696592654 - x'(t)$

differentiate

$y'(t) = -x''(t)$

plug into bottom formula

$-x''(t) = - (x(t) - 6.173)^2 - (-\pi + 5.696592654 - x'(t)) + 2.805$

After that point, I could use some help.

Comment: Um isn't this the exact question as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622702/differential-equations-question)? It was closed because it was unclear. Maybe instead of posting the same exact question and hoping it won't get closed again, you could edit the original question to make it more clear?

Comment: How would you suggest I make it more clear Aiden Chow?